# \n in Bash string and equality check

Tags: bash, shell

I have this:

```
if [ "$(./bin/ft_putendl_fd_test.bin)" != "NO__\n" ]
then
    echo "Error on ft_putendl_fd."
fi
```

The binary outputs this: `NO__\n`, where `\n` is actually the ASCII char `20`, not just `\\n`.

However, I always get `Error on ft_putendl_fd.`.

I've tried comparing against `$'NO__\n'` but it doesn't seem to work either.

I am using Bash 3.2.

Comment: I've changed it slightly since the first one didn't even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I'd found is this:

```
if [ "$(./bin/ft_putendl_fd_test.bin | cat -e)" != "$(echo 'NO__' | cat -e)" ]
then
    echo "Error on ft_putendl_fd."
fi
```

Comment: I'd go with @JoSo's solution (just test for equality with `NO__`, letting `bash` trim the trailing new lines). But if you insist on comparing for strict equality, so that would reject the program's output if it didn't have a trailing newline, or had two, then you could use `if cmp -s <(./bin/ft_putendl_fd_test.bin) <(printf 'NO__\n');`

Answer (score 5):

Note that the sequence `"\n"` won't produce a newline character. You can use `$'\n'` (not portable) or just embed the newline as text:

```
myno="NO__"$'\n'
myno="NO__
"
```

But that's not the problem here, because command substitution is defined to remove all trailing newlines anyways.

That means your test must be

```
[ "$(./bin/ft_putendl_fd_test.bin)" != "NO__" ]
```

In very few cases the remove-newlines feature might produce ambiguity (when you need to distinguish by number of trailing newlines). You can't turn it off easily, but it's possible:

```
x=$(./bin/ft_putendl_fd_test.bin; echo x)
x=${x%x}

[ "$x" != "NO__
" ]
```

Or simply:

```
[ "$(./bin/ft_putendl_fd_test.bin; echo x)" != "NO__
x" ]
```

Comment: You could also use `$'NO__\n'`, since `$'...'` is just (yet another) form of quoting.

Comment: @rici: True, but not portable neither

Comment: @conradk: Come on, please un-un-accept this answer. It's the right answer to your question. No need to be stingy :)